# Getting source rectangles method wont work, why?

Tags: c#, xna

Right now, I'm working on a little Jump'n'Run game in XNA. I decided to load textures from a tileset,
and designed a method for getting the source rectangles of a bigger rectangle. Within the method, the calculated rectangles are being added to a list, and the list is returned at the end of the method. However, the method doesn't seem to work properly. When trying to get a rectangle from a given index out of the list, I'm getting a index out of range exception. I tried this with several numbers, it still wont work. here is my method for getting the rectangles:

```
public static List<Rectangle> getSourceRectangles(Rectangle original, int partWidth, int partHeight)
        {
            List<Rectangle> rlist = new List<Rectangle>();
            int ix, iy;
            ix = original.Width / partWidth;
            iy = original.Height / partHeight;

            for (int x = 0; x < ix; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < iy; y++)
                {

                    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x * partWidth, y * partHeight, partWidth, partHeight);
                    rlist.Add(r);
                }
            }

            return rlist;
        }
```

I save the return value in a global Container class.
this is were I get the error: (ist just the constructor of the NormalTile class!)

```
public NormalTile(int _TextureIndex,Rectangle _rect)
        {

            this.rect = _rect;
            this.TileTextureIndex = _TextureIndex - 1;
            this.tex_rect = Global.TileTextures[TileTextureIndex];//HERE
        }
```

Why is this even Happening?

Comment: don't know why you have an out of range, but if with and height of the part are all the same *why* you need an array? Just calculate the offet on the fly would be probably faster than picking the object from the list

Comment: Can you debug it? What is the value of `TileTextureIndex`?

Comment: Yea, i can Debug it. The value of `TileTextureIndex` is, in this case, 0.